# Giving bytes as argument to an exe using Python 3

Tags: arguments, byte, python-3.2

I have an exe that I need to open using Python 3.2.3. I also need to pass an argument in the form of bytes to the exe. I try doing something like:

```
argument = '\x50'*260
subprocess.call([command, argument])
```

This works fine but when I try to give a non-printable character as the argument like '\x86', it gets converted to '\x3f'. Printing the argument gives the following error:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\x86' in position 262: character maps to <undefined>
```

So I tried doing it using os.system:

```
command = "C:\myfile.exe "+b"\x50"*260
os.system(command)
```

But obviously, this leads to a type error. Does anyone have any suggestions to get this thing done?

Answer (score 0):

It can't be done. The thing is that what subprocess does is pretend to type commands into the command prompt. Do you have access to the source of myfile.exe? You can easily represent bytes as a string or number.